# How to concat all ffmpeg inputs without mapping them in the filter using windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm running multiple runs of the ffmpeg concat filter on multiple files using Windows batch file script. I don't always know how many files exactly need to be concatenated and the problem is that ffmpeg doesn't automatically concatenate the inputs unless you map them all. For example, if I have to join eight files, I use the following filter mapping scheme:

```
 -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]concat=n=8:v=1:a=0"
```

If I have to join only 4 files later in the script, I have to change it to:

```
 -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0"
```

I had hoped not entering any mapping would automatically take all the inputs in order. I'm disappointed to find that it only takes the first two and ignores the rest. I tried simply:

```
 -filter_complex "concat"
```

and it "guessed" the mapping according to warnings, but completely ignored all inputs after the second.

There is no way to do this with ffmpeg alone, so I'm seeking a way to do this with the Windows batch script.

---

An example of a complete and working command is:

```
set commands=-filter_complex "[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]concat=n=8:v=1:a=0","crop=1064:800" /
-crf 30 -an -movflags +faststart -loglevel quiet -stats

ffmpeg -ss 00:00:36.737 -t 00:13:33.630 -i 1201.avi /
-ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:13:51.397 -i 1202.avi /
-ss 00:00:00.033 -t 00:13:06.052 -i 1203.avi /
-ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:17:31.617 -i 1204.avi /
-ss 00:17:31.551 -t 00:00:00.067 -i 1204.avi /
-ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:15:07.907 -i 1205.avi /
-ss 00:15:07.840 -t 00:00:00.067 -i 1205.avi /
-ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:02:36.990 -i 1206.avi /
%commands% 12-concat.mp4
```

My goal here is that I can set `commands` (and/or other variables) once in the script, instead of having to change it each time the command has more or less inputs.

Comment: Not possible with `ffmpeg` alone, but you could provide the appropriate labels via external scripting.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if not exist "inputs.txt" (
    >&2 echo File inputs.txt not found.
    exit /b 1
)

set /p "savefile=Save file: "

set "inputs="

for /f "tokens=1-3" %%A in (inputs.txt) do (
    set "inputs=!inputs!-ss %%~A -t %%~B -i %%~C "
)

call :buildcommands 8 1064:800 30

echo ffmpeg %inputs% %commands% %savefile%
exit /b 0


:buildcommands  maps  [width:height]  [crf]
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "ubound=%~1-1"
set "crop=%~2"
set "crf=%~3"
set "maps="

rem Set defaults if not defined.
if not defined crop set "crop=1280:720"
if not defined crf set "crf=23"

rem Build maps string.
for /l %%A in (0 1 %ubound%) do set "maps=!maps![%%~A]"

rem Build entire string.
set commands=-filter_complex "%maps%concat=n=%~1:v=1:a=0","crop=%crop%"^
 -crf %crf% -an -movflags +faststart -loglevel quiet -stats

rem Set global commands.
endlocal & set commands=%commands%
exit /b 0
```

This will build the inputs from file and commands from
`call` arguments.

You can use the preset defaults by:

```
call :buildcommands 8
```

so that crop is `1280:720` and constant rate factor is `23`.

input.txt would be like:

> ```
> 00:00:36.737 00:13:33.630 1201.avi
> 00:00:00.000 00:13:51.397 1202.avi
> 00:00:00.033 00:13:06.052 1203.avi
> 00:00:00.000 00:17:31.617 1204.avi
> 00:17:31.551 00:00:00.067 1204.avi
> 00:00:00.000 00:15:07.907 1205.avi
> 00:15:07.840 00:00:00.067 1205.avi
> 00:00:00.000 00:02:36.990 1206.avi
> ```

It is mostly data so I do not know how you
could improve it's input into the script.

Remove the echo in front of `ffmpeg` to make it work instead of just echo.